# C - copying directly from memory using memcpy

Tags: c, memory, memcpy

This is purely a homework assignment question, since I'm aware that you really shouldn't be trying to do this in real life. But I've been trying to get this right. Say we know the permanent start position of where we want to copy and the exact size of the chunk of memory we want to copy. So say our source is a stack from 0x28000 to 0x2C0000. The stack grows downwards, so we're given a pointer to the top of the stack (0x2C0000). We want to copy STACK_SIZE bytes over to a second stack, the top of which is at 0x30000. Basically something like this:

```
                Stack 1            Stack 2
       /--+-------------------+-------------------+--/
          |        ABXLQPAOSRJ|                   |
       /--+-------------------+-------------------+--/
      0x280000           0x2C0000            0x300000
                              ^                   ^
                              |                   |
                         Top of stack 1     Top of Stack 2
```

If we have to use memcpy, we would have to start at 0x28000 right? (I'm not entirely sure in which direction memcpy reads; from higher address to lower or vice versa) Would this be correct?

```
void* s = (void *)source_stack_bottom      //where source_stack_bottom is 0x280000 in this case
void* d = (void *)dest_stack_bottom    //which is 0x2C0000
memcpy(d, s, STACK_SIZE)          //STACK_SIZE is just a variable with the stack size
```

I can't think of why it shouldn't work, but then again I'm still rather confused about how C allocates memory at times so...

EDIT:: Oops, variable confusion. Fixed now.

Comment: *"Since I'm aware that you really shouldn't be trying to do this in real life"* - Ummm... why do you say that?  There are many legitimate reasons for copying a block of data with `memcpy`.  Whoever told you that doesn't know what they are talking about.

Comment: There was some funny business with the variables in your example code; I tried to fix it, but the comments didn't match with the memcpy() call.  I'll just let you fix it the way you meant it to be.

Comment: Also, don't cast the return value of `malloc` in C.  You don't need the cast because any pointer type can be implicitly (and safely) converted to a `void*`, and it can actually hide an error.

Comment: Well, it's less this and the fact that I was told never to make pointers directly into memory because you might end up overwriting something important. But it would make sense in kernel coding (which this is part of a sort of toy practice for).

Comment: @user1777900: Or image processing, or hardware interfacing... etc.  We're talking about C here, how do you propose to stay away from pointers exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A naive implementation of `memcpy()` would be something like this:

```
void naive_memcpy(void *destt, void *sourcet, size_t size)
{
   char *source = (char *)sourcet;
   char *dest = (char *)destt;
   for(size_t s = 0; s < size; s++){ *dest++ = *source++; }
}
```

So yes, it counts upwards from the start of `source` and `dest`

Comment: Except for the dereferencing of `void` pointers (which just isn't allowed), what's naive about this example? I think it meets all of the requirements of a compliant `memcpy()` implementation.

Comment: I would've almost missed the dereferencing of void ptr @CarlNorum. Btw, yeah you're right, nothing naive about it..

Comment: It would likely be written in instructions which take advantage of larger block copies assuming it were available (which it will be on modern CPU's)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `memcpy()` counts up from the base addresses you pass to it.

You might very well need to do something like this if you ever end up writing 'bare-metal' sort of OS-less software for embedded systems, or possibly if you're implementing an operating system or kernel yourself.